# "Linked" Shapes in Affinity Designer

Tags: affinity-designer

Is it possible to have multiple instances of one shape that are all updated once you have changed the original shape?

Comment: I think you are talking about symbols - tutorial [here](https://web-crunch.com/how-to-use-symbols-in-affinity-designer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using symbols is aready written.

There's still left another way: Placed Affinity documents are linked copies which get changed if one edits the original. It's made easy. One can take the original under edit wth a double click.

NOTE: Placing takes whole document, also the otherwise empty page. Fortunately it's transparent if not otherwise specified.